# Multiple Select with Rails Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a Collection_select, with Multiple set to true

```
 #views/courses/new
<%=collection_select(:course, :department_id, Department.all, :id, :name, {},
:multiple =>true,:size => 8,:class=> "text")%>
```

in My Models

```
#deparment Model
has_many :courses
#Course Model
belongs_to :deparment
```

I want a situation such that if a course has more than one department selected from the Multiple select list, this details is saved in the course Table. My Current Implementation saves just the first selected department for a course, and discards  the rest. 
Please how do i achieve this.

```
def create
@course = Course.new(params[:course] || [])
if @course.save
  redirect_to courses_path, :notice => "Course Created Successfully"
else
  redirect_to new_course_path
  flash[:alert] = "Error Creating Course"
end
end
```

Thank You

Comment: so does this mean that course can have many departments?

Comment: Yes , it does, but not Necessarily

Comment: then you need to change your associations. you need to create a new table that joins courses and departments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first..
You should have associations like this.

**department.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
```

**course.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
```

and than you can have **views/courses/new** like this.

```
<%=text_field_tag :course_name)%>
<%=select_tag(:departments, options_from_collection_for_select(Department.all, :id, :name),:multiple =>true,:size => 8,:class=> "text")%>
```

and **create action** will be like this.

```
def create
  @course = Course.new(params[:course_name] || [])
  if @course.save
    params[:departments].split(',').each do |id|
      @course.departments << Department.find(id)
    end
    redirect_to courses_path, :notice => "Course Created Successfully"
  else
    redirect_to new_course_path
    flash[:alert] = "Error Creating Course"
  end
end
```

**migration for joining table**

```
class CreateCoursesDepartments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :courses_departments do |t|
      t.integer :course_id
      t.integer :department_id

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank You so Much, do i have to make any change to my Migrations?,the else block is always executed when the create action is called? Am I Missing something?

Comment: You just need to have a table `courses_departments`. Make this table by the migration i have in my updated answer. Else block will execute when there is an error while creating course.

Comment: Thank You so Much, Solved the Issue

Comment: One Last doubt, In a course view,how do i get the courses in a department? with this particular relationship?

Comment: I didn't get your question. What you want to do? For which department you want to get courses as one course can belong to many departments?

Comment: I have a Courses View(index), that shows all Courses and the corresponding departments,  so if a course belongs to one department,just that department is shown, if it belongs to more than one department, the comma seperated list is shown. i have this :@courses= Department.all(:include => :courses, :conditions => ["courses.id = ?",])

Comment: So, you want to show list of courses and in the next column, a comma separated list of departments to which each course belongs?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want to achieve

Comment: May be you should do something like this, `@courses.each do |course| course.name, course.department.collect(&:department_name).join(',')`

Comment: i am assuming you have column `department_name` in departments table.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Has And Belongs To Many (HABTM) association for both your objects. Take a look at this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: Thank You so Much, an understanding of this equally helped.